# Xcode not recognizing CGFloat / UIFont / CGSize while using Objective-C with Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I created a new Swift project and tried to import my existing Objective C code into the Swift project. Everything is going fine except, Xcode 6 Beta 5 is complaining about `CGFloat` `UIFont` `CGSize`...The error I see is

> Expect a type

and

> Unknown type name 'CGFloat'

right next to some of my methods. I thought Swift should be friendly with Objective C and accept all my Objective C code but unfortunately, this is not the case.

Any Idea?, suggestions, or comments, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: `import UIKit`?

Comment: pNre, importing UIKit works... thanks

Answer (score 82, accepted):

just Add this in which you are facing error

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: Add `import UIKit` in your swift file

Answer (score 15):

Swift

```
import CoreGraphics
```

or

```
import UIKit
```

If you'd like. (UIKit includes CoreGraphics)

Answer (score 4):

If you tried to import existing Objective-C code than first of all you create one Objective-C header file in your Swift project. . .

after clicking that, editor asked for creating Bridging-Header, you must click yes:

[image]

these creates *yourSwiftProjectName-Bridging-Header.h* file . . .

Now, import your existing objective-c file in your project & simply import your header file in Bridging-Header.h file for example,

if your objective-c file is viewController.h & viewController.m than in Bridging-Header.h file write one line code:

```
#import "viewController.h"
```

I think, this code works for you . . .

Comment: Hi iHart, thanks for the reply. Actually dragged the files from my old project to the new and I did click Yes when it ask me to confirgure and Objective-C bridging header...But it did not solve the problem for me

Comment: I think, after creating Bridging header file.. create new objective-c header .h & also create implementation .m file in you new project . . . after that you can select whole code (cmd+a) & copy from your old objective-c file and paste into new created .h & .m file . . . I hope, these works

Answer (score 0):

In multi module envirompment it can be because of wrong setting `.modulemap`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665560/4770877) or umbrella header does not include it