# no umbrella header found for target, module map will not be generated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I trying build [CKCountdownButton](https://github.com/cybertk/CKCountdownButton) as a framework in Xcode 6.3, it complains with

**warning: no umbrella header found for target 'CKCountdownButton', module map will not be generated**

Then when I import this framework in other project, it failed with **No such module 'CKCountdownButton'**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add a `CKCountdownButton.h` in framework fixed this issue.

I think the umbrella header means the header file with same name like Framework

Comment: In other words, make sure the framework header matches the module name.

In my case I had created a new framework target named "MyFramework macOS" (which generated `MyFramework_macOS.h`). I then changed the module name to "MyFramework", but I didn't change the header. I fixed the umbrella header issue by renaming the header to `MyFramework.h` and updating the exports within it to match the new module name (`MyFramework_macOSVersionNumber` to `MyFrameworkVersionNumber`, etc.).

Answer (score 34):

I found another solution, **Xcode** provides a way to specify **umbrella header** through **Module Map File** configuration.

[image: snapshot]

The contents of `module.modulemap` should be:

```
framework module Foo {
    umbrella header "Bar.h"

    header "other-header.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

Comment: Complete reference for the modulemap syntax here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language

Answer (score 8):

That target needs to have at least 1 Swift file. Check that you have Swift files added to the target

Answer (score 6):

**Custom framework module map(.modulemap) and Defines Module(DEFINES_MODULE)**

[[Module and .modulemap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213694/4770877)

Public file structure:

```
header_1
  header_1_1
header_2
```

Mark all headers which should be exposed for consumer as public(header_1.h, header_2.h, header1_1.h). `Headers` **public** section[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511627/4770877) or you get next error.

```
//For example in umbrella.h
Include of non-modular header inside framework module '<module_name>'

//or in upper .h file
'PBURLConnectionStub.h' file not found
```

`modular headers` - `.h` files which included into `.modulemap`:

- .modulemap `umbrella` keyword from `umbrella.h`
- .modulemap `header` keyword.

Modular headers can import **only** modular headers

Create an `umbrella file` - any `.h` file (or autogenerated `<product_name>.h` for Framework target). Let's call it `Umbrella.h`

Add root `.h` files into `umbrella file`(`Umbrella.h`). All imports from this files will be added automatically

```
//Umbrella.h file
#import "header_1.h"
#import "header_2.h"
```

Use or create a custom `.modulemap` file. You can call the `.modulemap` file as you wish, after compiling it will be called `module.modulemap`. Also I would not recommend you to call it as `module.modulemap` because it can cause unpredictable changes of this file

`module.modulemap` which is generated by default:

```
//the same for Objective-C and Swift framework
framework module SomeModule {

    //umbrella header "<umbrella_name>.h"
    umbrella header "Umbrella.h"
  
    export *
    module * { export * }
}

//unique for Swift framework
module SomeModule.Swift {
    header "SomeModule-Swift.h"
    requires objc
}
```

**`umbrella header`**

Expose **all** `module headers` recursively. Generates next code

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule {
    //explicitly define all modular header
    header "header_1.h"
    header "header_2.h"
    header "header_1_1.h"
}

//using
import SomeModule

header_1
header_2
header_1_1
```

**multiple modules**

.modulemap can contain multiple modules. One of them must have the same name as `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME`

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule
framework module SomeModule2

//using
import SomeModule
import SomeModule2
```

**Submodule `module`**

When you import Outer module you are able to use headers from sub module

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule {
    module Submodule1 {
        header "header_1.h"
    }
}

//using
import SomeModuleSwift.Submodule1
//or even
import SomeModuleSwift

//availability
header_1
```

**explicit submodule `explicit module`**

You are not able to use module name for submodule header(as you can do by default as shown in previous example)

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule {
    explicit module Submodule1 {
        header "header_1.h"
    }
}

//using
//import SomeModuleSwift //Error: Cannot find 'header_1' in scope
import SomeModuleSwift.Submodule1

//availability
header_1
```

**Dependencies between explicit submodules `export`**

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule {
  explicit module Submodule1 {
      header "header_1.h"
      export Submodule2
  }
  explicit module Submodule2 {
      header "header_2.h"
  }
}

//using
import SomeModuleObjC.Submodule1

//availability
header_1
header_2
```

**Work with Umbrella**

`module *` works only with **`umbrella`**, if not you get

```
Inferred submodules require a module with an umbrella
```

```
//.modulemap
framework module SomeModule {
  umbrella header "Umbrella.h"

  module * { export * }
  export *
```

next code is generated

```
framework module SomeModule {

  //module * { export * }
  module header_1 {
    header "header_1.h"

    export header_2 
    export header_1_1 
  }

  module header_2 {
    header "header_2.h"
    
    export header_1 
    export header_1_1 
  }

  module header_1_1 {
    header "header_1_1.h"
    
    export header_1 
    export header_2 
  }

  //export *
  export header_1 
  export header_2 
  export header_1_1 
}

//using one of them
import SomeModule.header_1 
//or 
import SomeModule.header_2
//or
import SomeModule.header_1_1 
//or
SomeModule

//availability
header_1
header_2
header_1_1
```

When some file can not be found next error is occurred

```
Error: Cannot find 'header_name' in scope
```

To see the effect use `explicit module`

`module *` - creates submodule for every `modular header` inside `umbrella`

`export *` - export all submodule into current sub/module

If we use `module * { }` instead of `module * { export * }` and `import SomeModule.header_1` nothing changed we steal can use all `modular headers` when import a single submodule. It is safety because parent module `SomeModule` has an access to all submodules

```
import SomeModule.header_1

header_1
header_2
header_1_1
```

If we use `explicit module * { }` instead of `explicit module * { export * }` and `import SomeModule.header_1` we get error

```
import SomeModule.header_1

header_1
//header_2 //Error: Cannot find 'header_2' in scope
```

Producer:

**Defines Module(DEFINES_MODULE)**

```
Build Settings -> Defines Module
If YES - Xcode generates .modulemap. If `MODULEMAP_FILE` is not specified Xcode try to generate it automatically
```

**Module Map File(MODULEMAP_FILE)**

```
Build Settings -> Module Map File
Path to custom `.modulemap` file
The result file `module.modulemap` will be generated and embedded into .framework
```

Consumer:

**Import Paths(SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS)**

```
Build Settings -> Import Paths
Path to custom `.modulemap` file
```

Comment: should this `import SomeModuleObjC.Submodule1` change to import `SomeModule.Submodule1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 'GoogleToolbox'. It happened when I tried to update my pod repo and some error happened. Just did 'pod install' from terminal on the project folder and everything got ok.